Spring Boot multiple datasources - Is there a simpler way?
I am trying to learn how to use multiple Datasources in Spring Boot and the examples I am seeing are so complex. From "Spring Boot" autoconfiguration you now suddenly have to manually configure everything: you have to define packages with Entities and Packages with Repositories and you have to manually create TransactionManager & EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.
So now I have to constantly update Package Paths for

basePackages in @EnableJpaRepositories
packages() in return
entityManagerFactoryBuilder

and these can't be refactored automatically if I decide to rearange Classes.
Is there a simpler way? Like defining different Datasources and then using Annotations on Entities to specify where they should be saved.
Or maybe even manually configuring EntityManager for every Datasource but then using Annotations on Entities to specify which EntityManager should be used.
And can I avoid separately specifying Packages for Entities & repositories? Suddenly there is so much overhead configuration.
Here is the example Application I am currently using
https://github.com/ivoronline/springboot_db_datasource_SaveDifferentEntitiesInDifferentSchemas
Schema1Config.java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  basePackages      = "com.ivoronline.springboot_db_datasource_diffentitiesdiffschemas.schema1.repository",
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "schema1EntityManagerFactoryBean",
  transactionManagerRef   = "schema1TransactionManager"
)
public class Schema1Config {

  //=========================================================================================================
  // DATA SOURCE PROPERTIES
  //=========================================================================================================
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("schema1.spring.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties schema1DataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }
  
  //=========================================================================================================
  // DATA SOURCE
  //=========================================================================================================
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource schema1DataSource() {
    return schema1DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }
  
  //=========================================================================================================
  // ENTITY MANAGER FACTORY BEAN
  //=========================================================================================================
  @Bean
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean schema1EntityManagerFactoryBean (
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder,
    DataSource                  dataSource
  ) {
    return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
          .dataSource(dataSource)
          .packages("com.ivoronline.springboot_db_datasource_diffentitiesdiffschemas.schema1.entity")
          .build();
  }

  //=========================================================================================================
  // SCHEMA 1 TRANSACTION MANAGER
  //=========================================================================================================
  @Bean
  PlatformTransactionManager schema1TransactionManager(@Qualifier("schema1EntityManagerFactoryBean") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emfb.getObject());
  }
}


What kind of databases? I mean, what vendor?

GitHub contains application.properties that is configured for Oracle Database.
But that is irrelevant. The same code/approach applies to any database.

No there isn't. This is the way to do it. When you need multiple instances or decide to configure things manually this is the only way. JPA provides no way to specify what to use for a db connection on the entities (luckily).

If it is the same database but a different schema you can just specify which schema to use for JPA with the @Table annotation providing the schema keyword.

@ivoronline Oracle have a native dblink so you can use one jdbc-connetion processing two databases.

You mean to use Table Annotation on Entity to specify Schema? That is fine for some use cases but I think this will only do "SET SCHEMA" => that is specify default schema for unqualified objects. But if you acctually want to connect to different schemas using different users then this doesn't work. Or if you have Scheam Based Multitenanvy where the same Entitiy is in all Schemas then you can't define Schema.
